# Youtube - preventing ads of my competitors on my videos

Tags: google-adsense, video, advertising, youtube

I want to start and upload to youtube every day a new video for my commercial use.
The videos are suppose to serve existing clients and potential clients and are given free to everyone .

My problem is that I don't want that my competitors ads will be presented inside my video.
And by mistake my potential clients will be going to the competitor site because they think it is the competitor's video.

Is the any way to disallow ads (or certain category) in my movies? I am willing to pay for that service.

**Edit 1**

To make it clear. 
I am uploading videos to youtube with my brand on it, but this video is not promoted, regular user.
I don't want to see other ads **inside** my video.
By mistake I can have a competitor inside my video.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, don't want to display competitors video along my your tube video's sidebar, any help much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the YouTube help page titled ['Adding sites to a filter list'](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=172795):

> As a YouTube content partner, you can filter specific AdSense
>   advertiser domains appearing next to your YouTube videos.
>
> Here's how to filter a specific AdSense advertiser domain:
>
> 1. Sign in to your Adsense account.
> 2. On the AdSense Setup tab , click the Competitive Ad Filter link.
> 3. Click on the "AdSense for Content Host" subtab halfway down the page.
> 4. In the text box, enter the domains that you want to block from AdSense ads.
> 5. Enter URL that is displayed on the ad for that website. Enter one URL per line. You can add up to 500 URLs.
> 6. Click "Save Changes" to add these sites to your competitive ad filter.
>
> Changes to your filter list should be reflected on your site within 30
>   minutes.

You could also try the AdSense [category filters](https://www.google.com/adsense/site-targeted-ad-review) and [competitive ad filters](https://www.google.com/adsense/filter-online) in the Adsense setup area.

To completely turn off ads displayed inside your YouTube videos:

1. Log in to YouTube
2. Click your username in the top right of the screen.
3. Click the 'Settings' link under the 'My Account' header.
4. Choose the 'Manage Account' link in the left sidebar.
5. Scroll to the bottom, and choose 'do not allow advertisements':
   [image: youtube turn off advertising]

You may also wish to consider using a video sharing service that depends upon in-video advertising less heavily, such as [Vimeo.](http://vimeo.com)

Comment: I dont think you got me, I edit my post. I dont have an adsense account.

Comment: @fatnjazzy I've updated my answer to show how to turn adverts off. (I don't think you can filter them without an AdSense account.) I also suggest trying [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com) if you want to share videos without bombarding viewers with ads.